# Provisioning profile error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, provisioning

It is always the error I get when I don't use the Xcode after a while.

I check I should have the active provisional profile in the keychain.

I am building the app for ad hoc development.

Why the error still exists?

[[image: Provisioning profile]]]1]

[image: Compile error screen]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a distribution code signing identity (cert) for a debug build.  The distribution code signing should only be used for your app store builds.  You should create a new cert and profile for development.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

Provisioning profile always create me problem and it is a headache for me all the time.

Just fix by 2 actions:

1) Yes, I used the distribution profile than development profile. I have erased all profiles in the keychain. Then go to the Apple Developer account, and create a new "development" profile, and then download and install it in the keychain.

2) I go to the "General" tab, and click the "Automatically manage signing" box under the "Signing" session.

Now all working fine!